# Как добавить рамки для таблицы

Tags: android

Есть некая таблица. Как добавить рамки внутри таблицы?

`XML` файл прилагается.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/numpad_background" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_one"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_two"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_three"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_3" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_four"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_4" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_five"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_5" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_six"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_6" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_seven"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_7" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_eight"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_8" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_nine"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_9" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonstar"
        style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_star"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_star" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_zero"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonpound"
        style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_pound"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_pound" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15825611 ?

Comment: @pavlofff, если добавить `margin`-ы, ничего не меняется

Comment: Используйте свойства android:divider и android:showDividers="middle". Так же смотрите другие ответы по ссылке

Comment: добавил в тег `<TableLayout>` следующие строки `android:divider="@color/divider_color"
 android:showDividers="middle"` и как-то разницы 0, что не так?